# Main.xml not being updated

Tags: java, android, xml, view

Can someone look over my main.xml code really quick and make sure I'm not doing any stupid mistakes? It isn't displaying any of this. It's displaying the old main.xml. I saved it, restarted eclipse but it won't display the new code. Whenever I run the code it tells me I have errors in my code. But it doesn't show errors and on the second run it runs the old version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/PixLogo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:text="Take Photo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm calling the ImageView and Button onCreate. But it won't display the new changes (the logo image, the button text, the background color)

Comment: Yup, tried cleaning and restarting and still won't take the new changes.

Comment: If you actually try to build and start it, what the application is doing? If just works, may be Eclipse problem.

Comment: It's loading the layout that main.xml had previously. I tried uninstalling the app but that didn't work. It won't adopt the changes in the layout I've made.

Answer (score 0):

If there are errors, it should show in Problem View. Please make sure your project is set to Build Automatically

for probolem view - Go to Windows - Show View - Other - General - Problems

Comment: Problems is open on my bottom tab. It shows me some warnings, missing contentDescription attribute on image, etc. But no errors.